# localeCompare array with null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I'm sorting my array I get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null
```

What I've tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="userLastSyncTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sortable sortDevicePlatform orderDevicePlatformByASC">Device Platform</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
var TestArray = ["iOS 7", null, "iOS 8.4", null, null, null, "iOS 9"];

ShowUserSyncTable();

function ShowUserSyncTable() {
    var tableRecord = '';

    // Loop through all the returned records and add them to select box
    for (var i = 0; i < TestArray.length; i++) {
        tableRecord += "<tr id=" + "" + "><td>" + TestArray[i] + "</td></tr>";

    }

    $('#userLastSyncTable').find('tbody').html(tableRecord);
}

$(".sortDevicePlatform").click(function () {

    var clickedDevicePlatformSorting = $(this).hasClass('orderDevicePlatformByASC') ? 'orderDevicePlatformByDESC' : 'orderDevicePlatformByASC';

                $('.sortDevicePlatform').removeClass('orderDevicePlatformByASC').removeClass('orderDevicePlatformByDESC');
            $('.sortDevicePlatform').addClass(clickedDevicePlatformSorting);
    // Sort the sync list based on device platform
    TestArray.sort(function (a, b) {

        if (!a) {
            // Change this values if you want to put `null` values at the end of the array
            return -1;
        }
        if (!b) {
            // Change this values if you want to put `null` values at the end of the array
            return +1;
        }

        if (clickedDevicePlatformSorting == 'orderDevicePlatformByASC' && a) return a && b ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1;
        else if (b) return a && b ? b.localeCompare(a) : 1;
    });

    ShowUserSyncTable();
});
```

How do I go about sorting the array with null values?

Update Fiddle for testing:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2up76u1/2/)

**Expected out come:**

**One click show:**

iOS 7, iOS 8.4, iOS 9, null, null, null, null

**Another click show:**

iOS 9, iOS 8.4, iOS 7, null, null, null, null

Comment: Where do you want your `null` values to go? Up the list or down the list?

Comment: Why do you even want null values? Want to remove them?

Comment: @Chris Beckett. What do output expect after sort.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Check my new updated fiddle, It gives you more of an idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9f9gymh/)**.

Remove `orderDevicePlatformByASC` class name from clickable `<th ...>`. Because, its initial appearance is not sorted. Use this for sorting.

```
TestArray.sort(function (a, b) {
     if (clickedDevicePlatformSorting == 'orderDevicePlatformByASC' && a)            
        return  b ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1;
     else if (b) 
        return a ? b.localeCompare(a) : 1;
});
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want :), Update your answer with that new JSFiddle

Comment: please check my answer. remove `orderDevicePlatformByASC` for first appearance

Answer (score 11):

You cannot call a function on `null`. You have some `null` values in your array. So when you try to `sort` these values, it crashes.

You can protect your code to avoid that.

```
TestArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (!a) {
       // Change this values if you want to put `null` values at the end of the array
       return -1;
    }

    if (!b) {
       // Change this values if you want to put `null` values at the end of the array
       return +1;
    }

    if (sorted)
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    else
        return b.localeCompare(a);
});
```

But in my opinion, you should get rid of this `null` values in the array. You can filter them :

```
TestArray = TestArray.filter(function(val) {
    return val != null;
});
```

Comment: How do I show the iOS version first instead of the null values? then when clicked again show the null values first then iOS versions?

Comment: Read the comments in my code. Reverse `-1` and `+1` if you want to put `null`at the end of the array.

Comment: `!a` and `!b` will also work for empty strings `""`, zeros `0`, `undefined` and `NaN`.

Comment: @VisioN true. But i don't think it's a bad thing

Comment: if there is `var sorted = false;` what should result be

Answer (score 1):

Try ternary operator:

```js
var TestArray = ["iOS 7", null, "iOS 8.4", null, null, null, "iOS 9"];
var sorted = true;
var fn = function(a, b) {
  if (sorted)
    return a ? a.localeCompare(b) : 1;
  return b ? b.localeCompare(a) : -1;
};

document.write("<pre>");
TestArray.sort(fn);
document.write(JSON.stringify(TestArray));

document.write("<br/>");
sorted = !sorted;
TestArray.sort(fn);
document.write(JSON.stringify(TestArray));

document.write("</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0w5ejd5q/2/

```
TestArray.sort(function(a, b) 
{
    if (sorted && a!=null)
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    else if(b!=null)
        return b.localeCompare(a);
});
```

Comment: i think there should be one more `else` block required which returns `-1` if ascending and 1 if descending otherwise your code looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can do like this:

```js
tableData.sort((a, b) =>
  a[sorting.field] != null && b[sorting.field] != null
    ? reversed * a[sorting.field].localeCompare(b[sorting.field])
    : null
);
```

This will separate the null value to one place

Answer (score 0):

The complete method will be like this:

```
function sortNullColunm(shortingOrder givenArray,sortingField) {
  let resversed = shortingOrder === 'asc'? 1 : -1;

  givenArray.sort((a,b)=>a[sortingField]!=null && b[sortingField]!=null
    ? reversed * a[sortingField].localeCompare(b[sortingField])
    : null
  return givenArray
}

console.log(sortNullColunm(desc,array,fieldname));
```